# Meteor's EthBlocks.latest.number not updating

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, meteor, web3-providers

Created a very simple Meteor app to display the current block number using `ethereum:block`.

**Problem:** Even though the current block number is displayed when the page loads, it does not update both on the page and when running `EthBlocks.latest.number`

The valaue of `EthBlock.latest.number` updates only when the page is refreshed.

Shouldnt the variable `EthBlocks.latest.number` updates whenever `geth` detects a new block?

**client/currentBlock.html**

```
<head>
  <title>myDapp</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> currentBlock}}
</body>

<template name="currentBlock">
  <h1>Current Block</h1>
  <p> {{ currentBlock }} </p>
</template>
```

**client/currentBlock.js**

```
    import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
    import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

    import './currentBlock.html';

    Template.currentBlock.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
      EthBlocks.init();
    });

    Template.currentBlock.helpers({
      currentBlock() {
        return EthBlocks.latest.number;
      }
    });
```

**client/init.js**

```
if (typeof web3 == 'undefined')
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

Geth is started using

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:3000"
```

Comment: does it work if you refresh your browser?

Comment: @thefett Yes it does update when I refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question:
[Automatically update account balance with web3.js without polling](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25733/automatically-update-account-balance-with-web3-js-without-polling?rq=1)

To summarize, unfortunately an intuitive system that just has things update isn't quite there yet, but you can use filters to listen for a new block